# Optimising a compare query

Tags: mysql, compare

I've got two table which are exactly the same - products and products_temp. I want to compare the two table and i'm currently using the query below which works fine if there are not many products in each table, however I now have about 10,000 in each and it takes forever to run and then dies with an error 'mysql server has gone away'.

Please have a look at the query below and advise how I can optimise it

```
SELECT MIN( id ) AS id , product_id, product_name, program_id, program_name, deeplink,   price, image_url, merchant_category, category_id, category_path, brand, last_updated, tab
            FROM (
                SELECT id , product_id, product_name, program_id, program_name, deeplink, price, image_url, merchant_category, category_id, category_path, brand, last_updated, 'Temp' AS                   tab
                FROM products_temp AS alias1
            UNION ALL 
                SELECT id , product_id, product_name, program_id, program_name, deeplink, price, image_url, merchant_category, category_id, category_path, brand, last_updated, 'Current'                   AS tab
                FROM products AS alias2
            )AS alias_table
            GROUP BY id
            HAVING COUNT( id ) =1 #
```

Comment: When you say "compare the two table", what *exactly* are you trying to do?  Looking at your existing query, it appears you're finding the *difference* between the tables (i.e. those records that exist in only one table, but not the other) - but for clarity, is that what you're after?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate difference between tables in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430922/how-to-calculate-difference-between-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes that is right, get the difference between the two tables. Before this query I empty the products_temp table, populate it with the new data and then compare it with the products table to see which products have been added (temp)/deleted (current) then populate an array of these from the result of the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will apparently ALWAYS return every ID, either from the "Temp" or the "Live" table, thus returning every row.  What you may actually be looking for is...  From all the records in the "Temp" table, do they already exist in the "Live" table, or are they new and need to update / refresh.  To get this answer, I would do a left-join something like

SELECT
      tmp.*,
      if( products.id IS NULL, 1, 0 ) as NotOnLiveFile
   from
      products_temp tmp
         left join products
            on tmp.ID = products.id

No need to group by, nor the HAVING clause.  If the product is already ON file, what do you want to do with it... update the live values with that from Temp?  If the record is "NotOnLiveFile" do you want to add those?  You have all you need in one result set with this approach.

If this is your intent, you could always do a correlated update (for existing entries), or insert (if NOT on live file yet).

Comment: To give you an idea, this is for an affiliate site. This is part of the script that gets the product data from the feed. What the query should (and I'm pretty sure it does) do is get all products that exist in products but not in products_temp (Current) and get all products that exist in products_temp but not in products (Temp). What I do then is loop through the results and if tab == Current then I add this to a $deleteArray() and if tab == Temp I add it to a $addArray(). I then create a table for both of these in the actual site database (rather than the feed database) and run a script...

Comment: which then loops through the add and delete tables and updates the actual products table of the main site and adds/deletes the products accordingly. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @DerekCarlisle, actually no.  By creating some sort of graphic (with text since you are a young user (points), it may not allow you to paste graphics.  But show the context of what you are trying to do, why you would have one table have both records to be added and deleted and why.  The process itself is not completely clear, nor where your "loop" is handled for insert vs deletes.

Comment: Don't think I can use graphics unfortunately so I'll try and make it more clear. I have an affiliate marketing website which sells products  and I run a script daily which populates the website database with products/brands from a feed. In order to check if any new products have been added or removed from the feed since the script was last ran I have a separate database which when the script has ran creates a temporary table ('products_temp'), populates this with ALL products and then compares this with another table ('products'). So the first instance, there will be no products in the...

Comment: 'products' table, therefore a new table will be created in the main database (the websites database) which will list all the products and the 'products_temp' table in the feeds database will also be populated. The next time the script is ran, the products_temp table is truncated and then filled with all products from the feed again. This is then compared with the 'products' table (which contains all products from the feed the day before) and if there is any difference, whether a product has been added or deleted in the feed then another table is created in the main database with only those...

Comment: that have been added or deleted (so two 'delta' tables will be created if some have been added and some deleted). The main website will then run its own script and look at these delta tables and add/delete the necessary products from the main products table. The reason I do two scripts is because the compare one will take too long to do on the main website so I do this outside of the website on another domain and then the script for the actual site only takes a few seconds because its simply adding/deleting products from a table (rather than comparing tables etc). Hope thats a bit more clear?

Comment: @DerekCarlisle, with all my years, and complex queries / environments I've dealt with, I'm just not grasping your scenario without SEEing the data.  Sorry.

Comment: OK no problem, it's difficult to explain in text, would it be possible for me to send you the applicable sql and php files?

Comment: I think your query from earlier does a similar thing to be honest. All those with NotOnLiveFile = 1 are the new products and all those with 0 already exist. However, the only problem is this only tells me what is new in the products_temp table. It doesn't tell me what already exists in the products table but doesn't exist in the products_temp table to tell me which need deleting.

Comment: @DerekCarlisle, wait... are you trying to do replication of data from one server to another and THAT is why you need to know all the "Other" records?  I would suggest us going to a chat room instead of killing this now too long post/answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11935/discussion-between-derek-carlisle-and-drapp)